# Find most unique image from pair scores of a set of Images

Tags: mathematical-statistics, clustering, paired-data, metric

Long story short, I have a set of vectors for each image after training on a model. I'd like to find the most unique image from the scores generated by `cosine similarity`. The below 2D tensor array is the scores grid for `5` images, each being compared to each image.

```
tensor([[1.0000, 0.9849, 0.9606, 0.9227, 0.9508],
        [0.9849, 1.0000, 0.9737, 0.9462, 0.9654],
        [0.9606, 0.9737, 1.0000, 0.9836, 0.9825],
        [0.9227, 0.9462, 0.9836, 1.0000, 0.9789],
        [0.9508, 0.9654, 0.9825, 0.9789, 1.0000]])
```

I've tried using Standard Deviation and Interquartile range to find which has the max value to guess the most unique image. I'd like to know the correctness of my metric, and if not, what other approaches I can use to solve the above.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one "correct" metric. Reasonable approaches might be to find the image with the smallest mean similarity, or smallest median similarity, or smallest maximum similarity, or smallest minimum similarity. The first two metrics would find images that are on average different from all others. The smallest max similarity would find the image most different from any other, while the smallest min similarity would find the image most different from one other.

I might go for the image with smallest maximum similarity, as this will find an image that is different from all other images. When using average-type metrics, you might find an image that is highly different from almost all others but near-identical to another, which may or may not fit your goals. The maximum approach, however, will more highly rank images that are more distinct from *every* other image, even though they may be less distinct on average.

I don't see how the standard deviation or IQR helps here. Those values just indicate the *variability* with which an image matches others, but not *how well* it matches. You might have one image that matches all others fairly well with some variability, and another that matches all others poorly with the same variability, and IQR/standard deviation would treat those the same. Imagine you have a set of images that all differ by just 1 pixel. No matter what image you match against that set, you'll have a nearly invariant similarity measure, it doesn't matter if your query picture is totally unique (in which case the similarity measure is uniformly low) or another 1-pixel variant of the same image (in which case the similarity measure is uniformly high).

Comment: I've tried looking to the similarity metrics you've given but didn't find any reasonable reading material. For IQR and SD, I assumed that the row with most IQR would be the unique image but that wouldn't work ofcourse. The specific problem I'm working on is to extract the most unique image in a given set of frames (this is small) of a video.

Comment: More precisely, I'm working on is to extract unique frames from a video. What I'm trying to do here is to split it into chunks of 6 frames each and applying cosine similarity in that batch.